# Python 2.7.8 doesn't create Scripts directory and doesn't have easy_install on Windows 7

Tags: python, easy-install

I installed 2.7.8 after already having 3.x installed because I needed to use easy_install for a package that hasn't been ported to 3.x. After installing, I tried running 2.7.8 easy_install only to discover it didn't exist. The Python27 directory doesn't contain the Scripts directory at all that easy_install is meant to be in. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling thinking this was an error. I tried installing other 2.7 versions but there simply isn't any Scripts directory being created inside Python27. What am I missing?

Edit: I'm on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`easy_install` isn't actually a default modules/script on Python. You need to install the [setuptools](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html#installing-easy-install) module first. When installing setuptools, the 'Scripts' directory and `easy_install.py` will be automatically created for you.